# How to handle apostrophe in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to query business names in Wikidata using this [SPARQL query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ4830453.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Macy%5C%5C%27s%22.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D). I can't work out how to handle apostrophe's and other quotation (`"`) characters. I have tried escaping the chars with (`\`). 
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four options:

1. `'Macy\'s'`
2. `"Macy's"`
3. `'''Macy's'''`
4. `"""Macy's"""`

Any of these will work. The last two allow the string to span multiple lines. See [here in the SPARQL specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QSynLiterals) for the description of literal syntax, and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#grammarEscapes) for the description of character escapes in strings.